# Where is the best place to put support functions in a class?

Tags: python, class

In Python, I have a class that I've built.

However, there is one method where I apply a rather specific type of substring-search procedure. This procedure could be a standalone function by itself (it just requires a needle a haystack string), but it feels odd to have the function outside the class, because my class depends on it.

What is the typical design paradigm for this? Is it typical to just have myClassName.py with the main class, as well as all the support functions outside the class itself, in the same file? Or is it better to have the support function embedded within the class at the expense of modularity?

Comment: Make it static? `@staticmethod` I believe... And if you want to have related things, put them in the same file.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by to have `Is it typical to just have myClassName.py with the main class, as well as all the support functions outside the class itself, in the same file? Or is it better to have the support function embedded within the class at the expense of modularity?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `staticmethod`, like so:

```
class yo:
    @staticmethod
    def say_hi():
        print "Hi there!"
```

Then, you can do this:

```
>>> yo.say_hi()
Hi there!
>>> a = yo()
>>> a.say_hi()
Hi there!
```

They can be used non-statically, and statically (if that makes sense).

About where to put your functions...

If a method is required by a class, and it is appropriate for the method to perform data that is specific to the class, then make it a method. This is what you would want:

```
class yo:
    self.message = "Hello there!"
    def say_message(self):
        print self.message
```

My `say_message` relies on the data that is particular to the instance of a class.

If you feel the need to have a function, in addition to the class method, by all means go ahead. Use whichever one is more appropriate in your script. There are many examples of this, including in the python built-ins. Take generator objects for example:

```
a = my_new_generator()
a.next()
```

Can also be done as:

```
a = my_new_generator()
next(a)
```

Use whichever is more appropriate, and obviously whichever one is more readable. :)

Comment: When applying @staticmethod, how does the function get used? Can it be used only from within the class? Outside?

Answer (score 0):

If you can think or any reason to override this function one day, make it a `staticmethod`, else a plain function is just ok - FWIW, your class probably depends on much more than this simple function. And if you cannot think of any reason for anyone else to ever use this function, keep it in the same module as your class.

As a side note: "myClassName.py" is definitly unpythonic. First because module names should be all_lower, then because the one-module-per-class stuff is a nonsense in Python - we group related classes and functions (and exceptions and whatnots) together.

Comment: my_class_name.py, containing class MyClassName?

Comment: Depends on what you module contains, really - the point is: you don't have to have one module per class (nor to only have classes FWIW, functions are first class - no pun intended - citizens).

Answer (score 0):

If the search method you are talking about is really so specific and you will never need to reuse it somewhere else, I do not see any reason to make it static. The fact that it doesn't require access to instance variables doesn't make it static by definition.

If there is a possibility, that this method is going to be reused, refactor it into a helper/utility class (no static again).

**ADDED:**
Just wanted to add, that when you consider something being static or not, think about how method name relates to the class name. Does this method name makes more sense when used in class context or object context?